# Redirect with new tab in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I did a new tab function if I click a submit button using java script. The problem is the location of the parent page, if I click submit button there's a new tab but if I insert a code of location changing it doesn't work . Please help me.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("form").submit(function() {
     $("form").attr('target', '_blank');
     return true;
 });
 </script>

<form action="test.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.location.href='home.php';"/>
</form>
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: The new tab function is working. But the location of the parent page is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not really sure why you want to do this, it seems that mixing up the change of the `document.location.href` while the `submit` event is happening generates some kind of conflict.

In order to separate those two I came up with the following approach by postponing the setting of `document.location.href` using `setTimeout`. Here's a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WS49g/3/).

**HTML**

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="button" id="submit-btn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function () { document.location.href = 'test.php'; }, 100);    
    $("form").attr('target', '_blank');
    $("form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the attributes like:

```
attr("action", "location.php");
```

Then edit the onclick like `window.location.href`

Don't know if this is what you wanted and if helped

Comment: what action should I insert?